# BO RESTful API caches data

Tags: rest, business-objects

Here are my steps:

1. Create bo document with 2 prompts id = 1
2. Create bo 4.2 sp3 logon token.
3. Call `documents/1/parameters` - 2 prompt parameters are returned
4. Go to report designer and remove 1 prompt
5. Call `documents/1/parameters`

Expected: 1 prompt should be returned

Actual: 2 prompts are still returned (data was cached)

To get fresh data I need to re-login. **How can I get fresh data with the same BO token?** I tried to send `no-cache`,`no-store` etc http headers but it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to close and re-open it.  See section 8.1.6 of the guide.

Call `PUT /documents/xxx` with:

```
<document>
 <state>Unused</state>
</document>
```

then open it again.

Comment: I am not sure if this a good way but it works fine, thank you!

Comment: Sometimes this query returns http 500, I stayed with re-login.